# How can I verify my website?

Tags: security, web, verification

How can I make my website display a green label in the address bar of the browser:

[image: Example screenshot]

Do I need to just use https or is it a more complex process?

Answer (score 8):

Just using HTTPS (HTTP over SSL/TLS) does not give you the green address bar. You need an [extended validation certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate), where the CA verifies your identity, and not just your domain ownership.

EV certificates are more expensive than simple domain validated certificates.

On security.SE we have a related question: [What are the advantages of EV Certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/what-are-the-advantages-of-ev-certificate)

> For example, the EV certificate at http://www.paypal.com/ will make the browser show a green bar and display "PayPal, Inc." next to it. This is designed not only to link the certificate to the domain owner (like standard domain-validated certificates do), but also link it to a more physical institution (here, PayPal, Inc.). To do this, the CA must verify that the named institution is indeed the one owning the domain.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was not only about HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Green "Favicon" comes and differs from browser to browser and signalises the https connection

I would advice you not to try to implement this if you dont need it for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

You do need to make it [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) (which uses [SSL](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/Secure-Sockets-Layer-SSL) or secure socket layer. ) This basically encrypts the data that goes to and from your website. This can be a lengthy process depending on your web host but usually involves purchasing a certificate from your host.

Comment: But does this make sure that I am the owner of the site?

Comment: That is done by copyright more than SSL. SSL is used for sites that have valuable data being sent (eg eCommerce).

Comment: Yes I am aware of the uses of SSL. But I thought that the green bar is like https + a verification that you are the owner of the site.

Comment: Some interesting downvoting going on?!? See CodesInChaos' answer for more information.